# How to SUM all entries if the condition is 1

Tags: mysql

I want to count all values if the condition is equal to 1 in a specific column.

I am running this query:

```
$where_clause = '
    aatt.sid = "'.$mybb->input['sid'].'"
    AND att.att_month = "'.$mybb->input['att_month'].'"
    AND att.att_year = "'.$mybb->input['att_year'].'"';

$query = $db->query("
    SELECT SUM(aatt.present='1') AS total_present, SUM(aatt.absent='1') AS total_absent, aatt.sid, att.att_date, att.att_month, att.att_year, aatt.present, aatt.absent, aatt.leave_submitted
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."school_att att
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."school_att_attendance aatt ON (aatt.att_month=att.att_month)
    WHERE {$where_clause}");
```

But its counting the whole rows in a table. :/

Please help

This is my `school_att_attendance` table. As you see the `present` , `absent` columns. I just want if the `present = 1` then count all the `1s` from `present` 
 column. Same for the `absent` column.
[image]

Updated:
Here is the table's textual code;

```
> 
(`aaid`, `sid`, `present`, `absent`, `leave_submitted`, `att_date`, `att_month`, `att_year`) VALUES
(1, '2', '1', '0', '0', '4', '4', '2018'),
(2, '38', '0', '1', '0', '4', '4', '2018'),
(3, '36', '0', '1', '1', '4', '4', '2018'),
(4, '36', '1', '0', '0', '5', '4', '2018'),
(5, '2', '1', '0', '0', '5', '4', '2018'),
(6, '38', '0', '1', '0', '5', '4', '2018'),
(7, '38', '1', '0', '0', '6', '4', '2018'),
(8, '36', '1', '0', '0', '6', '4', '2018'),
(9, '2', '1', '0', '0', '6', '4', '2018'),
(10, '38', '1', '0', '0', '7', '4', '2018'),
(11, '36', '1', '0', '0', '7', '4', '2018'),
(12, '2', '0', '1', '0', '7', '4', '2018')
```

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Should be more like `SUM(CASE WHEN aatt.present = '1' THEN [column] ELSE 0 END) AS `total_present`

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated the question

Comment: Please add it as text, not image. That way we can use it in our own environments easier to help you out.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: add the example data as formatted text or insert statements (PHPMyAdmin export can eazy do this) not as image, And where is the expected result? Besides you only added example data for one table, in your query your are using two tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, updated the question with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sum you should use group by  related  to the ccorrect level of aggreagtion ind this case i suggest for sample  tt.att_date, att.att_month, att.att_year

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT SUM(aatt.present='1') AS total_present, 
           SUM(aatt.absent='1') AS total_absent, 
           aatt.sid, att.att_date, att.att_month, att.att_year
      FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."school_att att
                LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."school_att_attendance aatt 
                  ON (aatt.att_month=att.att_month)      
     WHERE {$where_clause}
     GROUP BY  att.att_date, att.att_month, att.att_year;")
```

Comment: You missed the `aatt.sid` in the group by

Comment: @JorgeCampos  . i have choosen of don't group by for aatt.sid  .. in this sample  .. is a group by sample for date , month and year

Comment: you have error ??  show the error message  .. wrong result  ..???  show a clear data result related  to your data sample  ..

Comment: Actually now I bring `GROUP BY` statement after  `WHERE` statement and now it seems to work. :)

Comment: @Uzma  correct .. answer  updated ..( these should raise a sintax error  .  )

Comment: @scaisEdge, Thanks, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, I only mentioned it because this is not sql ansi way and only mysql allows it. In this case the value from aatt.sid is unpredictable.

Comment: correct  ..  @JorgeCampos  .. only some version of mysql allows this behvior    .. otherwise must be assigned  specific sql_mode  ..